# swiperjs plus angularjs and slide recycling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a POS software with angularjs and I need to list thousands of products separated by pages of 30 products each, kind of like apps on an iPad. For that task I decided to use [Swiperjs](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/), an awesome library for creating slides, and since this angular app is designed for iPad, that library fits perfectly.

The problem is, I want to recycle slides so that I don't add 500 slides to the DOM, But it seems like the combination of Angularjs and Swiperjs is giving me problems.

First of all, I have an array with all my product data:

```
// In ProductListCtrl
$scope.productArray = [];
```

Then I separate the info in that array in 4 slides of 30 elements each:

```
var elements = $scope.productArray.slice(0, 120);
// slideGenerator is a function that seperates everything in slides
$scope.slides = Utilities.slideGenerator(elements, 30);
```

After that, I render the info in my DOM with a double `ng-repeat`:

```
<div id="bloque" class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Ahora estoy desarrollando sin complicarme, repito la lista y la oculto -->

    <div id="lista-productos" class="list oculto swiper-wrapper" ng-controller="ProductsListCtrl">
        <div class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
            <div class="elementos">
                <div class="productos">
                    <div ng-repeat="element in slide">
                        <span ng-if="element.name != 'empty'">
                            <button product="{{element.name}}" hasAttribs="{{element.hasAttribs}}" class="btn-product" ng-click="showElementAttribs($parent.$parent.$index, $index)">
                                <span ng-if="textIsHidden == true && element.image">
                                    <div class="elemImg" style="background-image: url({{element.image}}); background-size: contain;"></div>
                                </span>
                                <span ng-if="textIsHidden == false || !element.image">
                                    <div class="elemName">{{element.name}}</div>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-if="element.name == 'empty'">
                            <button class="pro_vacio"></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Until this point everything works perfectly. But then the user swipes, and swipes, and swipes again, and I try to load the new info like so:

```
if($scope.currentSlide >= 3) {
    // Update the data on the slide, $scope.wheel is simply
    // the slide I have to modify
    if($scope.wheel < $scope.slides.length) {
        $scope.slides[$scope.wheel] = Utilities.createSingleSlide($scope.productArray, $scope.currentSlide, 30);
        console.log("New slide created");
        $scope.wheel++;
            //$scope.$apply();
    }
    else {
        $scope.wheel=0;
    }

    swiper1.slides[0].clone().insertAfter(swiper1.slides.length - 1);
    swiper1.removeSlide(0);
    swiper1.swipeTo(swiper1.activeIndex-1, 0, false);
    swiper1.reInit();   

}

$scope.$apply();        
console.log("Slides", $scope.slides);
```

To me this seems like it should work, but it doesn't. It adds new slides every time and outputs some funky behaviour, when it should always contain the same number of slides, 4.

If I comment out the angular code:

```
    //if($scope.wheel < $scope.slides.length) {
    //    $scope.slides[$scope.wheel] = Utilities.createSingleSlide($scope.productArray, $scope.currentSlide, 30);
    //    console.log("New slide created");
    //    $scope.wheel++;
            //$scope.$apply();
    //}
    //else {
    //    $scope.wheel=0;
    //}
```

I sort of get the desired behaviour of the view recycling thing because I always get the same number of slides, 4, and I get a sort of infinite loop.

I've also tried this, after changing the info on the slide:

```
swiper1.slides[0].append()
```

But that changes the current slide that I'm viewing, which sucks, and doesn't work well.

So why does angular add new slides after modifying the data?